# How to describe such an abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a question studying by myself.

Let A be abelian satisfying $A/\mathbb{Z}_{p^m}\cong \mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ where m, n are integers and p is a prime.

How to fully describe such an abelian group A? I tried to solve it as follows:

Since A is finite, A has a decomposition as a product of cyclic groups. Maybe, at least one of factor has $\mathbb{Z}_{p^m}$ as a subgroup. Based on this idea, I find an example: $A=\mathbb{Z}_{p^m}+\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ where + is direct sum.

But I can't find another example, and also can't fully describe A. How can I show that? I need your brilliant help!:)

Comment: Do you know the structure theorem for finite abelian groups?

Comment: Of course! But it bothers me haha

Comment: Well, can this happen if the group is the direct sum of three groups? What if it is cyclic?

Comment: No, but for example, if $A=/mathbb{Z}_8+/mathbb{Z}_2$ and we consider A/<(2,1)>, then the factor group is actually $\mathbb{Z}_4$, you know. Direct sum of three groups... ummm, sorry but I have no idea.

Comment: Then what about the cyclic case?

Comment: cyclic case? Do you mean the cyclic group A of order $p^{m+n}$?

Comment: Yes, does that satisfy this condition?

Comment: Um, it is not easy to think. In order to consider this case, I must find an epimorphism $f: \mathbb{Z}_{p^{m+n}} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ with kernel $\mathbb{Z}_{p^m}$.

Comment: If you are familiar with the structure theorem, then finding such an epimorphism should not be too hard.

Comment: Ah, the factor group has an order $p^n$ and is cyclic, so it's obvious:) Your hint gives me time haha. Then, is it possible to find the other example?

Comment: It is possible to completely describe which groups satisfy this. Note that the group must have an element of order $p^m$, and that modding out by the subgroup generated by this element must "kill" all but one summand.

Comment: Could you write more specifically? I'm on the tip of my tougue.